# How to split string by nonalphanumeric values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe similar to the following:

```
df = data.frame(a=c("John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Doe John"), b=c(" 4 COW 1518 $ 75.75", " 1 BULL 1870 $ 84.00", " 2 BLK BULL 1877 $ 84.00"))
```

[image]

How would I split strings in the b column based on non-alphanumeric values so I would have the following?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `extract` from `tidyr` to split the column into multiple columns by capturing characters as a group with regex pattern

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
 extract(b, into = c('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'), 
       '^\\s*(\\d+)\\s+([A-Z ]+)\\s+(\\d+)\\D+([0-9.]+)', convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
#       a c        d    e     f
#1 John Doe 4      COW 1518 75.75
#2 Jane Doe 1     BULL 1870 84.00
#3 Doe John 2 BLK BULL 1877 84.00
```